# UnexpectedTagNameException while clicking dropdown menu item

Tags: python, selenium, select

I'm trying to get Python / Selenium to properly click on a dropdown menu and select "IT" but the best I could do was find the element and get an error stating I couldn't input text on what I have found.

Basically, the user would click on that menu and select IT or type IT and press enter.

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="id_tenant_group">Tenant group</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select name="tenant_group" nullable="true" class="netbox-select2-api form-control" data-url="/api/tenancy/tenant-groups/" data-filter-for-tenant="group_id" placeholder="None" id="id_tenant_group">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="2">IT</option>

  <option value="1">OT</option>

</select>



        </div>
```

When I inspect the element, I can see there is a span element that triggers an event showing another span where finally my option can be seen.

I cannot select via visible text, because other menus also contain the same "---------" visible text.

I've captured a couple screenshots to illustrate the issue, hope that helps.
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQdZ.png) [browser inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IgO1.png)

To be honest I am really lost, any suggestions will be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I've attempted the following:

```
tenant_g_element = Select(browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@id="select2-id_tenant_group-container"]'))
tenant_g_element.selectByVisibleText("IT")
```

But I've got the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on span
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
tenant_g_element = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID, 'id_tenant_group'))
```

because your  has the attribute id="id_tenant_group". There is no need to use By.XPATH...if you have some reason to need that, then you'll need to look up how to specify an XPATH (note that //span is going to find a <span>, not a <select> for example).

Comment: I've tested your method with the following code: _tenant_g_element = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID, 'id_tenant_group'))
tenant_g_element.select_by_visible_text("IT")_ and got the error **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view**

Comment: Well, that means that the item was found, but was not able to be scrolled into view, which a different problem.  I also notice that all the other answers you were given had the same new problem.The standard StackOverflow approach would be to post your updated code in a new question specific to this issue.

Comment: Hey Shaheed, I've found a way to post the data I needed via JSON, so getting this script to work won't be necessary anymore. I am thankful for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath seems wrong. You are trying to locate a span **tag** but you should locate **select** element. Additionally you should apply webdriver wait for of `select` element

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_tenant_group"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='id_tenant_group']/option[2]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='id_tenant_group']//options[contains(.,'IT')]")))
    select.select_by_visible_text('IT')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tested the code you supplied and got the following error: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subnet.py", line 35, in <module>
    select.select_by_visible_text('IT')
AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'**

Comment: @RenanHingel  Answer is updated. please try now and let me know.

Comment: Muzzamil, I'm thankful for your interest in this subject. I have tested your suggestion and got the following error: **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view** here's a screenshot of the complete code and also the error: https://imgur.com/oDogfIZ

Comment: @RenanHingel I have updated answer as per error message. Try Now.

Comment: Hey Muzzamil, I've found a way to post the data I needed via JSON, so getting this script to work won't be necessary anymore. I am thankful for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on elements, not on span
```

...implies that the element which you are passing to *Select* class is not a `<select>` node but a `<span>` element which isn't supported.

---

Seems your locator was identifying a `<span>` element instead of the `<select>` element. Hence you see the error. Additionally, `selectByVisibleText()` is not a valid *Python* method, instead you need to use `select_by_visible_text()`.

### Solution

To click on the option with text as **IT**, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  tenant_g_element = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.netbox-select2-api.form-control#id_tenant_group[name='tenant_group']"))))
  tenant_g_element.select_by_value("2")
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  tenant_g_element = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='netbox-select2-api form-control' and @id='id_tenant_group'][@name='tenant_group']"))))
  tenant_g_element.select_by_visible_text("IT")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tested your XPATH suggestion and I've got the following error :  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: The CSS_SELECTOR gave a different error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subnet.py", line 39, in <module>
    tenant_g_element.select_by_value("2")
<supressed to fit the reply>
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view